# JNI wrapper to openssl AES_ecb_encrypt not working

Tags: java-native-interface, openssl, aes

I'm doing a JNI wrapper to call AES_ecb_encrypt function from openssl.

The wrapper looks like this:

```
#include "aes.h"
#include <jni.h>
#include <string.h>


jbyteArray
Java_com_package_AESDecryptionFilterInputStream_encrypt( JNIEnv*  env,
                                          jobject  this,
                                          jbyte*  data,
                                          jbyte*  userkey,
                                          jint length,
                                          jint mode)
{
    const unsigned char* indata = (unsigned char*)data;
    const unsigned char* ukey = (unsigned char*)userkey;
    unsigned char *outdata = NULL;
    outdata = malloc(length);

    AES_KEY key;
    memset(&key, 0, sizeof(AES_KEY));

    if(mode == AES_ENCRYPT)
        AES_set_encrypt_key(ukey, 128, &key);
    else
        AES_set_decrypt_key(ukey, 128, &key);

    AES_ecb_encrypt(indata, outdata, &key, mode);

    jbyteArray bArray = (*env)->NewByteArray(env, length);
    jboolean isCopy;
    void *decrypteddata = (*env)->GetPrimitiveArrayCritical(env, (jarray)bArray, &isCopy);
    memcpy(decrypteddata, outdata, length);

    (*env)->ReleasePrimitiveArrayCritical(env, bArray, decrypteddata, 0);

    return bArray;
}
```

but, when I call it from java code to encrypt and then decrypt a string, the results aren't correct.

I'm declaring the library like this:

```
     static {
        System.loadLibrary("aes_ecb");
    }

    public native byte[] encrypt(byte[] data, byte[] userkey, int length, int mode);
```

I'm calling it like this:

```
        byte[] dec = "0123456789012345".getBytes();
        byte[] enc = encrypt(dec, decryptionKey.getBytes(), dec.length, 1);
        byte[] dec2 = encrypt(enc, decryptionKey.getBytes(), enc.length, 0);
```

The problem is that the plain text bytes are:

```
      dec = {49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53}
```

when I call encrypt:

```
      enc = {4, 106, -41, 38, -127, 71, 33, 77, -125, 105, -57, 82, -13, 93, 44, -125}
```

and then when I call decrypt I get:

```
      dec2 = {-103, 26, 73, -2, 64, -21, 14, -38, -51, 13, -7, 40, -83, 42, 119, -3}
```

dec and dec2 should have the same value but they don't!

What am I doing wrong?

I believe it might be something with converting signed char to unsigned char... I'm not sure about that piece of code where I cast directly jbyte* to unsigned char*...

Thank you!

Comment: do you know what the expected values for the enc[] array are? I dont think the casting will cause a problem. I  am guessing there might be a problem in the signed conversion when printing it in java

Comment: If I use java's crypto API, enc = {-28, -126, -104, 17, 105, -9, -46, 72, 72, 45, 1, 104, -61, -66, -80, -30}

which is then decrypted correctly using java's crypto API (i.e. dec2[] = dec[])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you get the function signature ?

```
"Java_com_package_AESDecryptionFilterInputStream_encrypt( JNIEnv*  env,
                                          jobject  this,
                                          jbyte*  data,
                                          jbyte*  userkey,
                                          jint length,
                                          jint mode)"
```

In JNI byte array will be passed as jbyteArray.
Function should be something like

```
Java_com_package_AESDecryptionFilterInputStream_encrypt( JNIEnv*  env,
                                          jobject  this,
                                          jbyteArray  data,
                                          jbyteArray    userkey,
                                          jint length,
                                          jint mode)
```

You should use javah to generate the signature
You can get the length of the array passed by `(*env)->GetArrayLength(env,data)`
Then you have to copy into a byte* by using `(*env)->GetByteArrayRegion(env, data, 0, length, nativeBytePointer);`
You will probably have to allocate memory for the nativeBytePointer

Comment: thank you, will try that. The signature i created it myself... didn't use anything to generate it

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you very much!, I did what you said, changed the signature to receive jbyteArray and then used GetByteArrayRegion to get jbyte *.
Thank you jogabonito!

Comment: Glad to help :-) Always try to use the generated signatures